# Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct primes. Can you prove the sequence $\{p^n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is not Cauchy under the given metric on $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

This is an elementary $p$-adic theory question. Granted $d(x,y)=|x-y|_q$ is a metric on $\mathbb{Q}$, and $|\cdot|_q$ is a norm such that

$$|x|_q=q^{-ord_q x}$$

where $ord_q x$ is the largest exponent $k$ such that $q^k|x$ if $x$ is an integer, and $ord_qx=ord_qa-ord_qb$ if $x\in \mathbb{Q}$, with $x=a/b$ for $a,b$ integers. Also $ord_q 0 = \infty$.

I want to show $\{p^n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is not Cauchy in the given metric. I want to come up with a fixed $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $N\in \mathbb{N}$ we can find $m\geq n>N$ which satisfy $|p^m-p^n|_q\geq \epsilon$. The latter expression becomes $|p^n|_q|p^{m-n}-1|_q\geq\epsilon$
but since $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime, we have $|p^n|_q=1$ so I'm left with

$$|p^{m-n}-1|_q\geq\epsilon.$$
Here's where my trouble begins since I couldn't find the right $\epsilon$ and $m,n$ so that the inequality holds for all $N$. I realize that if $p^{m-n}-1 \not\equiv 0 \pmod q$ then I'm done, but I cannot find the connection. Any ideas?

Comment: If you replace $\ge \varepsilon$ with $\le\varepsilon$, it will be both more consistent with the definition of a Cauchy sequence, and easy to prove.

Comment: But I want to show the sequence is not Cauchy. I'm using the negation of the definition of a Cauchy sequence, or maybe I'm not understanding your suggestion?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, it's me who didn't understand what you tried ro prove . It's late here…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restrict to $m = n+1$. While it might happen that $p-1$ is divisible by $q$, there is a fixed largest power $q^l$ that divides $p-1$ and taking $\epsilon$ smaller than the norm of that power will do.

Possibly I should add that you cannot always find $p^{m-n} -1 $ that is not divisible by $q$ for if $q \mid (p-1 )$ then $q \mid (p-1) \mid p^k - 1 $ for all $k \ge 0$.

Comment: The answer was hidden in the definition... thanks.